# Projecting is fetching automatically

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am using spring tool suite for development.one page is opened,and when i clicking on the page to edit,project is fetching completely.I donot want to fetch the project.

Before i click on the page,following is the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1uT4.png)

After i have clicked the page,following is the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwfpo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble understanding what you are asking, but... I think what you want is to not have your editor 'linked' with the package explorer.

You can do that by toggling the button at the top of the package explorer, with left-and-right arrows: [image]